# PHP Regex to remove nested form elements but not input elements

Tags: php, regex, forms, nested-forms

I'm modifying a PHP script that I have and it is currently outputting a nested form.  Something like:

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
<p>stuff here here, this may or may not be in a div, script, etc..</p>
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
<div>stuff here possibilly</div>
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 
<p>otherstuff this may or may not be in a div, script, etc..</p>
</form>
```

Nested form's are a no-no (IE hates them and basically causes the form to stop working), so I need to remove the nested form lines, but not the form items.  I need to remove the nested:

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
```

and

```
</form>
```

but not the outer `<form` and `</form>` or the input or submit stuff.

Is this possible to do with regex?

Note, the reason I just want to regex out the form rather than find the problem is because I know it will take some significant re-working to get rid of the double form... the regex solution is quick for now.

Comment: I think you're approaching this wrong. Don't go putting out fires of a defective script. Fix the script itself.

Comment: It cannot be done using regular expressions. Regular expressions cannot handle nesting. You can write a parser quickly for that specific task.

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regex http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127

Comment: @Truth, I know that, I even stated as much in my note.  The script isn't just a script... its drupal, with ubercart so simply "fixing" my particular problem is a longer thing.  I needed a fix today and regex will do it I think.  But you are right and it will get fixed the right way, just not today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that wasn't easy on but here's the code

```
preg_replace('@(<form[^<>]+>)((.|[\r\n])*)(<form[^<>]+>)((.|[\r\n])*)(</form>)((.|[\r\n])*)(</form>)@','$1$2$5$8$10',$html);
```

Comment: this works only for 1 form inside another,i did not test it for more complex cases,good luck

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for the effort, but you should know that HTML shouldn't be parsed with RegEx.

Comment: @Truth the question was specifically tagged as regex question,but if you have a better method please share it :)

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a try.  For my use, I will never have more than one within the other.  I'll post back and let ya know how it goes.